# ground loop on an adaptor board

Tags: grounding

I want to make a PCB on which [PowerBOost 1000 Basic](https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1nVnEvwkcs4QBHRXtiWimhhG2ibtq-Sk8) will be installed. The PowerBoost is a breakout board for a voltage regulator and has four GND pins. In this case is it better to connector the four GND pins to my PCB, or just connect one of the pins to the PCB? I wonder if the former would cause a ground loop.

Answer (score 1):

A ground loop or other coupled ground  concerns are a consequence of there being real impedance associated with real world ground. Even a PCB plane has some impedance. This is not meant to start an argument over ground loops and ground noise, but for this purpose is enough to say that if you have a sufficiently low impedance connection between the ground pins, then effects of ground loops are a non-issue.

In other words , **it is totally reasonable, and usually recommended, to connect all GND pins to the same, low-impedance ground.**

---

The regulator breakout is providing multiple ground connections for several purposes.

1. Reduce impedance of GND connection (e.g. in case a long cable is used) voltage drops of a few mV in VCC are usually well tolerated, but voltage drops or noise due to current spikes in GND w.r.t to your PCB can be problematic
2. A bad connection tends to have worse consequences when GND is disconnected vs VCC (brown out vs floating ground), so redundant grounds in case there is a broken pad or bad pin is a good idea.
3. Having extra pins is good for the mechanical strength of the connector, and what else to fill the extra pins than extra gnd pins that can be left floating safely in worst case

Comment: Thank you for your answer. To understand clearly I would like to ask some more questions. (1) On the breakout the GND next to Vin will carry much larger current than GND next to Vout, Then theoretically I'm having GND loop but this is okay since the voltage drop is small? (2)Is it also fine to attach 50cm long wires to the three GND pins on the breakout board and then connect the other ends of the wires together?

Comment: @Nownuri 1. If the ground on either pcb is coupled to a large, low impedance ground planes, and not doing anything unusual then there will not be any significant current difference between the ground wires, regardless of how close they are to Vin. A ground loop is introduced when there are multiple current return paths , but it is theoretical until  there is impedance and ground current, then it becomes noise and feedback. 2. It is fine to do so as long as current ratings are respected on your single pin ground connection

Comment: Another way to think of it is how would you arrange the traces if this regulator was on board, probably with a large ground plane, using four large ground wires to couple an external board is largely the same, no?